# spark RDD saveAsTextFile gzip

Tags: apache-spark

is it possilbe to save a spark rdd text file as gzip?

Can I run this somehow: `combPrdGrp3.repartition(10).saveAsTextFile("Combined")` and save it as gzip files?

Comment: I think you need to pass in a custom `OutputFormat` upon which you've set `setOutputCompressorClass`. May need to use `saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile` for this.

Answer (score 6):

use

```
import org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec
combPrdGrp3.repartition(10).saveAsTextFile("Combined", classOf[GzipCodec])
```

or

```
sc.hadoopConfiguration.setClass(FileOutputFormat.COMPRESS_CODEC, classOf[GzipCodec], classOf[CompressionCodec])
```

Comment: As far as I know lzo is not supported by default, right?