# How to save a DataFrame as compressed (gzipped) CSV?

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I use Spark 1.6.0 and Scala.

I want to save a DataFrame as compressed CSV format.

Here is what I have so far (assume I already have `df` and `sc` as `SparkContext`):

```
//set the conf to the codec I want
sc.getConf.set("spark.hadoop.mapred.output.compress", "true")
sc.getConf.set("spark.hadoop.mapred.output.compression.codec", "true")
sc.getConf.set("spark.hadoop.mapred.output.compression.codec", "org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec")
sc.getConf.set("spark.hadoop.mapred.output.compression.type", "BLOCK")

df.write
  .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
  .save(my_directory)
```

The output is not in `gz` format.

Comment: Related question about RDDs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32231650/spark-rdd-saveastextfile-gzip

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Spark 2.2+**

`df.write.option("compression","gzip").csv("path")`

**Spark 2.0**

`df.write.csv("path", compression="gzip")`

**Spark 1.6**

On the spark-csv github:
https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv

One can read:

> `codec`: compression codec to use when saving to file. Should be the fully qualified name of a class implementing org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CompressionCodec or one of case-insensitive shorten names (bzip2, gzip, lz4, and snappy). Defaults to no compression when a codec is not specified.

In this case, this works:
`df.write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").codec("gzip")\ .save('my_directory/my_file.gzip')`

Answer (score 37):

This code works for Spark 2.1, where `.codec` is not available.

```
df.write
  .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
  .option("codec", "org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec")
  .save(my_directory)
```

For Spark 2.2, you can use the `df.write.csv(...,codec="gzip")` option described here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=codec

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: In case of using "json" format, the compression does not get picked up

Comment: It looks like the keyword argument has been changed to `compression`. https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=codec#pyspark.sql.DataFrameWriter.csv

Answer (score 34):

With Spark 2.0+, this has become a bit simpler:

```
df.write.csv("path", compression="gzip")  # Python-only
df.write.option("compression", "gzip").csv("path") // Scala or Python
```

You don't need the external Databricks CSV package anymore.

The `csv()` writer supports a number of handy options. For example:

- `sep`: To set the separator character.
- `quote`: Whether and how to quote values.
- `header`: Whether to include a header line.

There are also a number of other compression codecs you can use, in addition to `gzip`:

- `bzip2`
- `lz4`
- `snappy`
- `deflate`

The full Spark docs for the `csv()` writer are here: [Python](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrameWriter.csv.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameWriter.csv) / [Scala](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameWriter.html#csv(path:String):Unit)

Comment: Thanks for linking to csv writer docs, and not giving a databricks only answer!

Comment: @LaurensKoppenol - Well, to be fair, the CSV support added to Spark proper originally started as the external Databricks CSV package [linked to](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv) in the accepted answer. :) That package is available to any Spark user to use, but starting with Spark 2.0 you don't need it anymore.

Comment: I had to use `df.write.option("compression","gzip").csv("path")` with Spark 2.2.

Answer (score 1):

To write the CSV file with headers and rename the part-000 file to .csv.gzip

```
DF.coalesce(1).write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").mode("overwrite")
.option("header","true")
.option("codec","org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec").save(tempLocationFileName)

copyRename(tempLocationFileName, finalLocationFileName)

def copyRename(srcPath: String, dstPath: String): Unit =  {
  val hadoopConfig = new Configuration()
  val hdfs = FileSystem.get(hadoopConfig)
  FileUtil.copyMerge(hdfs, new Path(srcPath), hdfs, new Path(dstPath), true, hadoopConfig, null)
  // the "true" setting deletes the source files once they are merged into the new output
}
```

If you don't need the header then set it to false and you wouldn't need to do the coalesce either. It will be faster to write too.