# How to save dataframe as text file GZ format in pyspark?( (but not in csv format)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have data frame like below

```
+-------+------+----+----+
|      a|     b|c   |d   |
+-------+-----------+----+
|    101|   244|   4|   1|
|    101|   245|   5|   0|
|    101|   313|   2|   0|
|    101|   380|   3|   0|
|    101|   902|   1|   1|
|    135|   303|   4|   0|
|    135|   381|   3|   1|
|    135|   386|   5|   1|
|    135|   393|   1|   1|
|    135|   396|   2|   1|
|    140|   247|   2|   1|
|    140|   313|   3|   0|
|    140|   380|   4|   0|
|    140|   558|   5|   0|
|    140|   902|   1|   1|
|    141|   240|   4|   0|
|    141|   275|   2|   1|
|    141|   387|   3|   0|
|    141|   388|   1|   1|
|    141|   528|   5|   0|
+------------+-----------+
```

How to save  above dataframe as GZ text file formate with field separator is `|` and after saving my output files shoud be part-00000.gz,part-00001.gz e.t.c

Comment: @ user6910411 : I want to save as data frame as a text file but not in csv file .this is not duplicate as above .

Comment: Sorry, maybe it wasn't precise enough. Since 2.0 the solution is the same as in the [Nick's Chammas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47274672/6910411) answer - use `compression` option. It will work with all file based sources that support compression.